# Why can't I create aggregate average date difference columns in SQL

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I want to create average date difference columns in SQL for a AB test data set I am working with but whatever I work with ends up with an error message.

[image: original data]

I tried to aggregate the tables but it didn't work, I'm still fairly new to sql so I'm confused!

```
SELECT
ab_group,
avg(datediff(install_date, conversion_date) as avg_install_2_purchase,
avg(datediff(assignment_date, conversion_date) as avg_assignment_to_purchase,
avg(count(purchases)/count(assignment_date)
from
table
group by ab_group
```

[image: output]
I was hoping the output would be like my image, in the data provided most conversions are null but I do have them in my data. I'm not sure why the code is failing?

Comment: What is the error message? Also please do not present your sample data as an image, rather provide it as a text so we can use it to help you. Follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I get the error about date_diff not being a function in big query and that my data types are incorrect (theyre not) and looking at the gbq documentation the function does exist

Comment: what data type you columns date related columns? are they string or date?

Comment: You are calculating DateDiff for one date compare to conversion_date where as all conversion_date values are NULL in your sample data. Why you are expecting values from that comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why we no use subqueries to make it all easier to read/understand/debug? I mean, yes, its a bit verbose, not usually the best choice in production, but it almost always helps in making things explicit, well outlined and very readable:

```
select 
 ab_group,
 avg_install_to_purchase,
 avg_assignment_to_purchase,
 if(coalesce(assignment_dates, 0) = 0, 0.0, purchases/assignment_dates) as ratio from 
(
   select 
       ab_group, 
       avg(install_to_purchase) as avg_install_to_purchase, 
       avg(assignment_to_purchase) as avg_assignment_to_purchase, 
       count(purchases) as purchases, 
       count(assignment_date) as assignment_dates
   from (
            select 
               ab_group,
               coalesce(abs(datediff(install_date, conversion_date, day)), 0) as install_to_purchase,
               coalesce(abs(datediff(assignment_date, conversion_date, day)), 0) as assignment_to_purchase,
               coalesce(purchases, 0) as purchases,
               assignment_date
            from `mydataset.mytable`
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

There are too many issues with your query, so before I will try to enlist them  - see corrected version of it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  ab_group,
  AVG(DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y',install_date), PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y',conversion_date), DAY)) AS avg_install_2_purchase,
  AVG(DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y',assignment_date), PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y',conversion_date), DAY)) AS avg_assignment_to_purchase,
  COUNT(purchases)/COUNT(assignment_date)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY ab_group
```

By comparing original and above query - you most likely can find all the issues - below are few of them

- There is no datediff() function - rather DATE_DIFF()
- that function accepts DATE types not STRING types, so you need to convert your string dates into dates of type DATE using PARSE_DATE() function
- DATE_DIFF also requires DATE_PART as a last argument, which was missed  - I assume it intended to be DAY
- There were multiple missing brackets
- and finally you attempted to do aggregation over aggregation (AVG(COUNT()/COUNT())

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this line:

```
avg(count(purchases)/count(assignment_date)
```

First, you are missing a closing parentheses.  Second, you can't nest aggregation functions.

I think you just intend:

```
count(purchases)/count(assignment_date)
```